# How to draw arrow at the start in the flow chart?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, block

I am confused how to draw arrow in the flowchart at the beginning and end. I used the following

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle,rounded corners, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=1.5cm, text centered, text width=2cm, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=2cm, draw=black, fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm]
 \node (s1)[process]{Comp $C_1(t)$};
\node (s2)[process,right of =s1, xshift=2cm]{Comp  $C_2(t)$};
\node (s3)[process, right of =s2, xshift=2cm]{Comp $C_3(t)$};
\node (s4)[process,above of=s3, yshift=2cm]{Comp $C_4(I)$};
\node (s5)[process,right of =s3, xshift=2cm]{Comp $C_5(t)$};
\draw [arrow] (s1) -- node[above] {$\beta $} (s2);
\draw [arrow] (s2) -- node[above] {$\gamma$} (s3);
\draw [arrow] (s3) -- node[right] {$r$} (s4);
\draw [arrow] (s3) -- node[above] {$\mu$} (s5);
\draw [arrow] (s4) -- node[above] {$r$} (s5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But I want the following figure.

[image]

Comment: You can shift the coordinates to use as new positions for arrows. For example, from `s1` to down, you  can use `\draw [arrow] (s1.south) -- ([yshift=-1cm]s1.south);`

Answer (score 2):

You can use relative coordinates for that. For example, `++(1,0)` is the point 1 unit to the right of the previous coordinate, so `\draw (s1.south) -- ++(0,-1);` draws a 1cm long line down from the bottom end of `s1`.

In the code below I also did a couple of other modifications. It's generally recommended to use `\tikzset{foo/.style={...}, ...}` over `\tikzstyle{foo}=[...]`, so I changed that.

Most notably I added the `positioning` library, and changed e.g. `right of=s1,xshift=2cm` to `right=of s1`. With that library and the slightly different syntax, the distance is calculated between the edges of the nodes, so you don't need the `xshift`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, positioning}
\tikzset{
startstop/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30},
process/.style={rectangle,rounded corners, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=1.5cm, text centered, text width=2cm, draw=black, fill=orange!30},
decision/.style={diamond, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=2cm, draw=black, fill=green!30},
arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
\node (s1)[process]{Comp $C_1(t)$};
\node (s2)[process, right=of s1]{Comp  $C_2(t)$};
\node (s3)[process, right=of s2]{Comp $C_3(t)$};
\node (s4)[process, above=of s3]{Comp $C_4(I)$};
\node (s5)[process, right=of s3]{Comp $C_5(t)$};
\draw [arrow] (s1) -- node[above] {$\beta $} (s2);
\draw [arrow] (s2) -- node[above] {$\gamma$} (s3);
\draw [arrow] (s3) -- node[right] {$r$} (s4);
\draw [arrow] (s3) -- node[above] {$\mu$} (s5);
\draw [arrow] (s4) -- node[above] {$r$} (s5);

\draw [arrow, <-] (s1.west) -- node[above] {A} ++(-1cm,0);
\draw [arrow] (s5.east) -- node[above] {B} ++(1cm,0);
\foreach \i/\t in {1/C,2/D,3/E,5/F}
  \draw [arrow] (s\i.south) -- node[left] {\t} ++(0,-1cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that the diagram is wider than the textblock in a standard `article`, if you haven't modified the margins in any way, I'd recommend making the diagram a bit narrower.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If we would like to write the text on these arrows what we have do which codes we have to use.

Comment: @draasma The same way you added text on the other arrows,  it's the same thing. For the four arrows drawn by the loop, if you want four different texts, do e.g. `\foreach \i/\t in {1/a, 2/b, 3/c, 4/d}`, and use `\t` in the  node text.

Comment: i tried to write the text over the arrows but it does not work.

Comment: @draasma Obviously I have no idea what you did wrong ("does not work" is not very descriptive in that sense), but see the updated answer.